# Variable does not exist

Tags: apex, class, string

This is confusing me and no matter how many times I read through it I can't seem to figure it out.

I'm getting a Variable does not exist: listOfDels error on the last line of code.

Can anyone see why?

```
// Loads of code above this...

public void GetCustomFields() {
 cf = [SELECT id, Email_to_send_confirmation_to__c, attachmentid__c, AccountID__c, courses__c, triggercheckbox__c, courses__r.Course_Notes2__c, courses__r.VenueNotesForConfirmation__c, Send_Confirmation_Automatically__c, has_confirmation_been_sent__c, courses__r.venue_address__c, courses__r.Course_Name__c, courses__r.Duration__c, courses__r.Course_Start_Date__c, courses__r.Start_Time__c, courses__r.Finish_Time__c, courses__r.Tutor2__c FROM Course_Sale__c WHERE id = :oppr];
 }

public void GetDelNames(){
  List<Delegate__c> dels = [SELECT id, Name, AccountID__c, Courses__c from Delegate__c WHERE AccountID__c =: cf.AccountID__c AND courses__c =: cf.Courses__c];
  String listofDels;
     for(Delegate__c del: dels){
     if(listOfDels == null) listOfDels = del.Name;
     listOfDels = listOfDels+ '<br/>'+del.Name;
}
}

public PageReference emailAtt()
{EmailTemplate template = [SELECT Id, Subject, HtmlValue, Body FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name = 'Training_Confirmation_Email'];

GetCustomFields();

String subject = template.Subject;
subject = subject.replace('{!Courses__c.Course_Name__c}', cf.courses__r.Course_Name__c);

String htmlBody = template.HtmlValue;
htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Courses__c.Course_Name__c}', cf.courses__r.Course_Name__c);
htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Courses__c.VenueNotesForConfirmation__c}', cf.courses__r.VenueNotesForConfirmation__c);
htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Courses__c.Course_Notes__c}', cf.courses__r.Course_Notes2__c);
htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('[ListOfDelegates]', GetDelNames(listOfDels));
```

Comment: `GetDelNames` method does not take any parameter.So why are you passing one?

Comment: listOfDels is defined inside the GetDelNames method so out of scope within emailAtt() Change GetDelNames to return a string type and return listofDels. Just call this method in emailAtt.

Comment: What you want to do is return listofDels from GetDelNames? So the void GetDelNames() should be a string GetDetNames(). When you call the function, just say GetDelNames() without passing any variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`listofDels` is declared as a variable local to method `GetDelNames()` but referenced outside of that method (in fact, inside another method `emailAtt()`.

If you want instance method X to reference a variable, then that variable must either be:

- Declared within the method
- Declared as an instance variable to the class
- Declared as a static variable to the class

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why I didnt do this first, I just put the lot inside emailAtt()